# Notepad++ I'm looking for a regexp to select all occurances of 'href="' that do not match 'href="javascript'

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is about the code editor Notepad++.

I'm looking for a regular expression that will solve the following problem:

I have a set of html files. I need to find all links in them that are not links to javascript functions. If I search for the string '`href="`' I get 342 results and if I search for '`href="javascript`' I get 301 results. I'd like to get at the 41 elements that are only in the first set. That is all links that are not to javascript function calls.

I'd be grateful if anyone more familiar with regular expressions than I currently am could help me out on this one.

Comment: In case that was unclear I'd like to apply the regular expression in notepad++'s search window.

Answer (score 2):

This will match urls that don't start with "j", which probably will work for you.

```
href="[^j]
```

Comment: thank you. This worked. It would exclude any relative links starting with a 'j' but since I know I was looking for 41 (from the searches described above) I know I got them all. So thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type of RegExp engine is used in Notepad++ but the extended regular expression would look like:

```
href="(?:(?!javascript).)
```

Comment: there does not seem to be a '?' in notepad++

Comment: I looked here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

Comment: the regexp: href="(javascript) finds all the javascript function calls but I have not managed to negate the (javascript) so far

Comment: sure could, any recommendations?

Comment: gvim for e.g. it has a windows compatibility mode which helps the starters

Answer (score 0):

PowerGrep w/ RegexBuddy - I use notepad++ and PowerGrep